# Fluent Builder pattern which returns root type

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns, builder

I want to create builder for my purpose, with such call chain:

```
User user = new CommonBuilder(new UserNode()).Root //generic parameter, currently is User
    .Group.Group.Folder.Build();
```

Here is the code, which I use:

```
public abstract class AbstractNode
{
    public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}

public abstract class AbstractNode<T> where T : AbstractNode<T>
{

}

public class CommonBuilder<T> where T : AbstractNode<T>
{
    public T Root { get; private set; }
    public CommonBuilder(T root)
    {
        Root = root;
    }
}

public class UserNode : AbstractNode<UserNode>
{
    private GroupNode _group;
    public GroupNode Group
    {
        get
        {
            if (_group is null)
            {
                _group = new GroupNode();
            }
            return _group;
        }
    }
}

public class GroupNode : AbstractNode<GroupNode>
{
    private GroupNode _group;
    public GroupNode Group
    {
        get
        {
            if (_group is null)
            {
                _group = new GroupNode();
            }
            return _group;
        }
    }

    private FolderNode _folder;
    public FolderNode Folder
    {
        get
        {
            if (_folder is null)
            {
                _folder = new FolderNode();
            }
            return _folder;
        }
    }
}

public class FolderNode : AbstractNode<FolderNode>
{

}
```

The problem is in the `Build()` method, which need to return `Root` from `CommonBuilder`, not the `File`.

Where must I place `Build()` method, which must be always called at the end of a chain, which returns `Root` of a builder?

Comment: If you have a root, shouldn't you have a list object or tree object?

Comment: @jdweng what do you mean?

Comment: It you have a root then you must have a tail (more than one object).  You referred to a "chain" which means more than one object, yet you don't have a chain.  I assumed the chain would be a list or tree.

Comment: @jdweng the root can be any `AbstractNode`, and this chain isn't tree or list, because only one node can be assigned to each other.

Comment: How can you have a chain with only one link?

Comment: @jdweng I'm sorry, seems that I don't understand you. I have this thing `User -> Group -> Group -> Folder`, how can I name it? It is a chain, isn't it? However, how can I return from this "chain" `User`?

Answer (score 1):

In case when it's required to make a chain the same object should be returned, even as another interface check [first](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2011/02/07/fluent-interfaces-in-c-net-with-expression-builder-method-chaining-and-rpg-games/) and [second](https://weblogs.asp.net/arturtrosin/builder-pattern-through-fluent-interface) examples of implementation Builder with Fluent intefaces

I've tried to implement your case to fit the role, check if it will fits your requirements:

```
public interface IGroup<T>
{
    IGroup<T> Group { get; }
    IFolder<T> Folder { get; }
}
public interface IFolder<T>
{
    T Build();
}
```

Builder implements all required interfaces. And returns itself in each call. In general you can put `Build` method in the builder itself and call it separately after the end of chain execution.

```
public class CommonBuilder<T> : IGroup<T>, IFolder<T> where T: INode, new()
{
    private T _root = new T();

    public T Build()
    {
        return _root;
    }

    public IGroup<T> Group
    {
        get
        {
            _root.MoveToGroup();
            return this;
        }
    }

    public IFolder<T> Folder
    {
        get
        {
            _root.MoveToFolder();
            return this;
        }
    }
}
```

Because of generics it's required to set some limitations on generic parameter which is done with `INode` interface

```
public interface INode
{
    void MoveToGroup();
    void MoveToFolder();
}
```

Testing user object

```
public class User : INode
{
    public StringBuilder Path { get; } = new StringBuilder();

    public void MoveToFolder()
    {
        Path.AppendLine("Folder");
    }

    public void MoveToGroup()
    {
        Path.AppendLine("Group");
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Path.ToString();
    }
}
```

And the call will looks like

```
var user = new CommonBuilder<User>().Group.Group.Folder.Build();
```

### EDIT

Maybe as a the first stage it makes sence to get rid of Fluent interfaces and implement logic using just a Builder:

```
public class FolderNode : INode<Folder>
{
    private readonly Folder _folder = new Folder();
    public Folder Build()
    {
        return _folder;
    }
    public void AppendGroup()
    {
        _folder.Path.AppendLine("Folder Group");
    }
    public void AppendFolder()
    {
        _folder.Path.AppendLine("Folder Folder");
    }
}

public class UserNode : INode<User>
{
    private readonly User _user = new User();
    public User Build()
    {
        return _user;
    }
    public void AppendGroup()
    {
        _user.Path.AppendLine("Group");
    }
    public void AppendFolder()
    {
        _user.Path.AppendLine("Folder");
    }
}

public class CommonBuilder<T, TNode> where TNode : INode<T>
{
    private readonly TNode _root;

    public CommonBuilder(TNode root)
    {
        _root = root;
    }

    public T Build()
    {
        return _root.Build();
    }

    public CommonBuilder<T, TNode> Group {
        get
        {
            _root.AppendGroup();
            return this;
        }
    }

    public CommonBuilder<T, TNode> Folder {
        get
        {
            _root.AppendFolder();
            return this;
        }
    }

}

public interface INode<out T>
{
    T Build();
    void AppendGroup();
    void AppendFolder();

}

public class Folder
{
    public StringBuilder Path { get; } = new StringBuilder();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Path.ToString();
    }
}

public class User
{
    public StringBuilder Path { get; } = new StringBuilder();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Path.ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var user = new CommonBuilder<User, UserNode>(new UserNode()).Group.Group.Folder.Build();
var folder = new CommonBuilder<Folder, FolderNode>(new FolderNode()).Group.Folder.Group.Folder.Build();
```

Comment: Very good! But the problem is that in this solution `CommonBuilder` can only has `User` as `Root`. Is it possible to have `Root`'s type not only `User`, but also `Group`, `Folder`, whatever?

Comment: In this implementation it can be any class that implements `INode` interface

Comment: Yes, but for example, I have `Report` node, which doesn't have functions from `INode` interface, what should I do then?

Comment: You can `implement` the interface in `Report` class. Somehow the data collected by the builder should goes to the result object. In classic Builder implementation, Builder "knows" the exact type => can fill them. In generic / current case Builder doesnot has that information, that's why the simpliest way is to implement interface on possible generic types

Comment: I have tried to divide builders by non generics, e.g. `UserBuilder`, `FolderBuillder` etc, but the problem is that I don't know which builder exactly returns, for example `public class UserBuilder : CommonBuilder<UserNode>, IUserNode<UserNode>`, what must be returned here `public IGroupNode<UserNode> Group => throw new NotImplementedException();`?

Comment: Could you maybe extend the question with more detail what you actually want to achieve. What you want to see as the result of the operation in the beginning of the question